# Eclipse IDE not showing correct outputs

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using eclipse(2021-06) to run a C++ code. My question is that even if I delete a print statement it is still printing next time I run the code. Not printing the correct outputs. What is the reason for this? I build the code several times but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure the code you're running is the code that's being compiled? Can you post more details about your workflow?

Comment: Did you save your files before compiling? Have you checked the modification date of your executable to ensure you are running the one that has just been compiled?

Comment: I saved the code and compiled and run several times without any issue. Then I deleted a print statement printf("test") inside a for loop which I used to test the code. But still I am getting that print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the code, general idea is that you are not building the project again before running it.
Try following:

1. Clean project
2. Build project
3. Run again

Comment: I build the project every time before run. I saved the code and compiled and run several times without any issue. Then I deleted a print statement printf("test") inside a for loop which I used to test the code. But still I am getting that print statement.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, there was an internal printf command in the code and eclipse does not have support printing matrices with bunch of rows. Only shows last set of rows. Thanks for all your help and suggestions.